# Switch view using intent (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have been trying to switch view using Intent and onClick. When i click on the button my app crashes. I have browsed trough similiar problems asked here but none of them seem to apply to what i have. Anyway, I was wondering if anyone could give me a vague hint on what is wrong with my code.

The button XML:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/shapes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SHAPES"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onShapes"/>
```

When button is clicked start Shapes.class (from MainActivity):

```
    public void onShapes(View view) {
    Intent startShapes = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Shapes.class);
    startActivity(startShapes);
}
```

Shapes.class, sets view to content_shapes:

```
package com.example.******.****.buttonns;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.******.****.R;

public class Shapes extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_shapes);
    }
}
```

content_shapes (the view i want to see when pressing the button):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.*******.*****.buttonns.Shapes">

    <TextView
        android:text="Helloooo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Shapes_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And i also put this in the Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".buttonns.Shapes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_shapes"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.********.*****.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I have been trying to figure out the fault for hours now.
By the way I am a total noob at Java, XML and Android Studio so dont hate me if I forgot something trivial.

Comment: What are the errors? At which line?

Comment: What should it do and what's it currently doing?

Comment: Instead of Intent startShapes = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Shapes.class); try Intent startShapes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Shapes.class); Please post the error you are getting when the app crashes.

Comment: Oh sorry, in the MainActivity it says "cant resolve symbol R"

Comment: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }`

Comment: Sync the project once again.

Comment: It works now, i changed getApplicationContect() to MainActivity.this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this :

```
Intent startShapes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Shapes.class);
startActivity(startShapes);
```

instead of this :

```
Intent startShapes = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Shapes.class);
startActivity(startShapes);
```